# How to use ElementTree in python to extract fields that meet specified conditions for XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree to extract xml file as a new xml file. I'm parsing xml file in the following way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("./VD.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML_Head version="1.1" listname="VD" updatetime="2021/11/19 17:08:00" interval="300">
    <Infos>
        <Info vdid="N1" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="N3" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T78" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
    </Infos>
</XML_Head>
```

How can I extract the vdid I want or delete the vdid I don’t want? For example, I want to keep the group with vdid=T74, and the expected XML output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML_Head version="1.1" listname="VD" updatetime="2021/11/19 17:08:00" interval="300">
    <Infos>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
    </Infos>
</XML_Head>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Starting from python 3.10 **(!!!)** you can use next XPath [`.//Infos/Info[@vdid!='T74']`](http://xpather.com/KctP52h3). It will return you all nodes which have to be removed from original tree, so you can just iterate over them and apply [`Element.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove). Notice, that you need to call `.remove()` on parent node, so you can firstly find `<Infos>` node using `root.find("Infos")` and than use simplified XPath [`.//Info[@vdid!='T74']`](http://xpather.com/AWzKy04q) to get needed `<Info>` nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the `vdid`(s) you want to keep in a set and then go through your xml file and remove the unwanted ones:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("./VD.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

vdid_to_keep = {"T74"}

infos = root.find("Infos")
for info_tag in infos.findall('Info'):
    if info_tag.get("vdid") not in vdid_to_keep:
        infos.remove(info_tag)

tree.write("./output.xml")
```

output.xml:

```
<XML_Head version="1.1" listname="VD" updatetime="2021/11/19 17:08:00" interval="300">
    <Infos>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21" />
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23" />
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21" />
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23" />
        </Info>
    </Infos>
</XML_Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML_Head version="1.1" listname="VD" updatetime="2021/11/19 17:08:00" interval="300">
    <Infos>
        <Info vdid="N1" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="N3" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T78" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21"></lane>
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23"></lane>
        </Info>
    </Infos>
</XML_Head>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
info_sub_list = root.findall('.//Info[@vdid="T74"]')

infos = root.find('.//Infos')
infos.clear()
infos.extend(info_sub_list)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<XML_Head version="1.1" listname="VD" updatetime="2021/11/19 17:08:00" interval="300">
    <Infos><Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21" />
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23" />
        </Info>
        <Info vdid="T74" status="0" datacollecttime="2021/11/19 17:00:00">
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="1" speed="54" laneoccupy="21" />
            <lane vsrdir="0" vsrid="2" speed="49" laneoccupy="23" />
        </Info>
    </Infos></XML_Head>
```

Comment: @balderman could you explain why xpath would be better in this case? (genuinely asking). It seemed to me that using a set like I did ensured better expandability and readability in case more vdid were to be added... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tranbi . If the library we use (ElementTree) let you find the elements using xpath - why we need to use custom code (like you do) in order to find elements?

Comment: @Tranbi, it allows you to search nodes with certain attribute value, which is neither better or worse, it's just another way. Your solution seems more generic for me though, the only way how you can improve it using XPath is to search for `<Info>` nodes with `vdid` attribute value not equal to `"T74"`, it will help you to get rid of condition inside loop: `infos.findall("./Info[@vdid!='T74']")`. **BUT (!!!)** it will work only with python 3.10+.